# Column ambiguously defined error. Working without pagination?

Tags: sql, oracle

***I just want to figure whats wrong with below query :-
If we remove the pagination Rownum part it works fine.
Mentioned is the query below:-
We have tried with removing pagination and it works but we are not able
to make it work with pagination and its giving ambiguity error. I can also see all columns are with their tableNames.***

--

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT a.* ,
    ROWNUM rnum
  FROM
(WITH TEMP_DCS AS (SELECT ACCOUNT_CYCLE_INV_DATE.ACCT_ID, ACCOUNT_CYCLE_INV_DATE.HIERARCHY_SOURCE, 
 ACCOUNT_CYCLE_INV_DATE.INV_DATE, ACCOUNT_CYCLE_INV_DATE.INVOICE_NUM, ACCOUNT_CYCLE_INV_DATE.DATA_GROUP, ACCOUNT_CYCLE_INV_DATE.BILL_SYSTEM_ID 
FROM
ACCOUNT_CYCLE_INV_DATE_302345 ACCOUNT_CYCLE_INV_DATE
WHERE DATA_GROUP=20180118
AND BILL_SYSTEM_ID = 6)
/* Formatted on 4/25/2018 2:26:23 PM (QP5 v5.115.810.9015) */
SELECT 
  /*+ leading(TEMP_DCS DIM_HIERARCHY FACT_TAX) full(TEMP_DCS)  */
  DIM_HIERARCHY.ACCT_LBL,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.ACCT_DESC,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.ACCT_FMT,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.ACCT_ID,
  DIM_LOCATION.ADDR1,
  DIM_LOCATION.ADDR2,
  DIM_LOCATION.ADDR3,
  DIM_LOCATION.ADDR4,
  DIM_LOCATION.ADDR5,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.ADMIN_ID,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.AGCY_HIER_CD,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.AGCY_HIER_NM,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.AGGREGATION_ATTR ,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.AGGLVLTYPE,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.AGGRFMT AS AGGLVLID,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.HPID,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.AGGRLBL,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.AGGR_CUSTOM_LABEL,
  REF_BPI_PROVIDER.AREA_ID,
  REF_BPI_PROVIDER.BC_DESC,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.WORK_CIRCUIT_ID_1,
  REF_BPI_PROVIDER.CB_DESC,
  REF_BPI_PROVIDER.CHANGE_BY,
  REF_BPI_PROVIDER.CHANGE_DT,
  FACT_TAX.CHARGE_GROUP_ID,
  REF_BPI_PROVIDER.CIC,
  DIM_LOCATION.CITY,
  FACT_TAX.CNTNUMBER,
  REF_BPI_PROVIDER.COMMENTS,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.COMM_SVC_AUTH_NB,
  FACT_TAX.SUM_AMOUNT_TAX,
  FACT_TAX.TAX_GROUP,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.FRGN_ACC_1,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.FRGN_ACC_2,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.GROUPTYPE,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.GROUP_LBL,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.GROUP_FMT,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.GROUP_DESC,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.GROUP_ID,
  DIM_LOCATION.HS_LOCATION_ID,
  DIM_LOCATION.HS_LOCATION_NAME,
 FACT_TAX.INTERNATIONAL_TAX_AMT,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.INV_CUST_NUM,
  FACT_TAX.INVOICE_NUM,
  FACT_TAX.INV_DATE,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.IP_SRV_ACC_NO,
  FACT_TAX.LOCID,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.MRK_AREA,
  DIM_LOCATION.MOW_CNTRYID,
  FACT_TAX.MOW_TAX_PERCENTAGE,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.MSTR_ACCT_NBR,
  REF_BPI_PROVIDER.ORIG_COMP_CD,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.ORIG_SYSACCT_ID,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.ORIG_SYSACCT_CD,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.PRODUCT_FAMILY_ID,
  REF_PRODUCT_FAMILY.PRODUCT_FAMILY,
  REF_PRODUCT_FAMILY.PRODUCT_FAMILY_DESC,
  TEMP_DCS.ACCT_ID,
  TEMP_DCS.HIERARCHY_SOURCE,
  TEMP_DCS.INV_DATE,
  TEMP_DCS.INVOICE_NUM,
  TEMP_DCS.BILL_SYSTEM_ID,
  DIM_SUB_ADDL_INFO.SUB_ACCT_ATTR1,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.PON,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.PORTID,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.PORTID1,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.PROVIDER_ID,
  REF_BPI_PROVIDER.PSEUDO_CIC,
  REF_PROD_TYPE.PRODUCT_TYPE_ID,
  REF_PROD_TYPE.PRODUCT_TYPE_DESC AS PTDESC,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.PRODUCT_TYPE_ID,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.RAO,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.REGN_CD,
  REF_BPI_PROVIDER.SBC_AFFL_IND,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.SBU_DESC,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.SBU_FMT,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.SBU_LBL,
  DIM_LOCATION.SERVICE_CTR,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.SERVICE_FMT,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.SERVICE_FMT2,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.SERVICE_FMT3,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.SERVICE_FMT4,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.SERVICE_ID,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.SERVICE_LBL,
  DIM_LOCATION.SITE_ALIAS,
  DIM_LOCATION.SITE_ID,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.SRC_BILLER,
  REF_BPI_PROVIDER.STATUS_CD,
  REF_STCNTRY.STCNTRYTXT,
  FACT_TAX.STCNTRY_ID,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.SUBACCTYPE,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.SUB_DEP_ID,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.SUB_ACCT_ID,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.SVCARRTYPE,
  REF_BPI_PROVIDER.SVC_PRVDR_DESC,
  REF_TAX.TAX_DESC AS TAXDESC,
  FACT_TAX.TAX_SURCG_IND,
  FACT_TAX.TAX_TYPE_CD,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.LEG_TCCUSTID,
  REF_TRANS_CODE.TRANS_CODE_DESC,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.LEG_TCINVID,
  FACT_TAX.TEL_PROVIDER_CD,
  FACT_TAX.TOT_TAX_TRANS,
  FACT_TAX.TOT_TAX_WITHLD,
  DIM_LOCATION.TO_END_USR_CITY,
  DIM_LOCATION.TO_END_USR_CUST_NAME,
  DIM_LOCATION.TO_END_USR_STATE,
  DIM_LOCATION.TO_END_USR_STREET,
  DIM_LOCATION.TO_END_USR_ZIP,
  FACT_TAX.TRANSCODE_ID,
  FACT_TAX.MOW_TAX_WORDING,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.WORK_CIRCUIT_ID_2,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.WORK_CIRCUIT_ID_3,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.WORK_CIRCUIT_ID_4,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.WORK_CIRCUIT_ID_5,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.WORK_CIRCUIT_ID_6,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.WORK_CIRCUIT_ID_7,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.WORK_CIRCUIT_ID_8,
  DIM_LOCATION.ZIP_CODE,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.BUNDLE_FAN,
  REF_CHARGE_GROUP.CHARGE_GROUP_ID,
  REF_CHARGE_GROUP.CHARGE_GROUP_DESC,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.DEP_ID,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.DLCI,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.DLCI1,
  REF_BPI_PROVIDER.EBAT_DESC,
  REF_BPI_PROVIDER.EDI_DESC,
  DIM_LOCATION.EOL_NUM,
  FACT_TAX.CURRENCY_CD,
  FACT_TAX.FFP_TAX_INC_IND,
  FACT_TAX.BAND,
  REF_PROD_TYPE.PRODUCT_TYPE_CODE,
  REF_CHARGE_GROUP.CHARGE_GROUP_CODE,
  REF_TRANS_CODE.TRANS_CODE,
  DIM_HIERARCHY.BILLER_SERVICE,
  DIM_LOCATION.LOCATION_ADDRESS
FROM DIM_HIERARCHY,
  REF_BPI_PROVIDER,
  FACT_TAX,
  DIM_LOCATION,
  REF_PRODUCT_FAMILY,
  TEMP_DCS,
  DIM_SUB_ADDL_INFO,
  REF_PROD_TYPE,
  REF_STCNTRY,
  REF_TAX,
  REF_TRANS_CODE,
  REF_CHARGE_GROUP
WHERE DIM_HIERARCHY.ACCT_ID         = TEMP_DCS.ACCT_ID
AND DIM_HIERARCHY.BILL_SYSTEM_ID    = TEMP_DCS.BILL_SYSTEM_ID
AND DIM_HIERARCHY.BILLER_SERVICE    = TEMP_DCS.HIERARCHY_SOURCE
AND FACT_TAX.INVOICE_NUM            =TEMP_DCS.INVOICE_NUM
AND FACT_TAX.BILL_SYSTEM_ID         = TEMP_DCS.BILL_SYSTEM_ID
AND FACT_TAX.INVOICE_NUM            = TEMP_DCS.INVOICE_NUM
AND FACT_TAX.INV_DATE               = TEMP_DCS.INV_DATE
AND DIM_HIERARCHY.BILL_HIERARCHY_ID = FACT_TAX.BILL_HIERARCHY_ID
AND DIM_HIERARCHY.ACCT_PART_KEY     = FACT_TAX.ACCT_PART_KEY
AND DIM_HIERARCHY.BILL_SYSTEM_ID    = FACT_TAX.BILL_SYSTEM_ID
AND DIM_HIERARCHY.BILL_SYSTEM_ID    = REF_PRODUCT_FAMILY.BILL_SYSTEM_ID
AND DIM_HIERARCHY.PRODUCT_FAMILY_ID = REF_PRODUCT_FAMILY.PRODUCT_FAMILY_ID
AND DIM_HIERARCHY.BILL_SYSTEM_ID    = REF_PROD_TYPE.BILL_SYSTEM_ID
AND DIM_HIERARCHY.PRODUCT_TYPE_ID   = REF_PROD_TYPE.PRODUCT_TYPE_ID
AND DIM_HIERARCHY.BILL_SYSTEM_ID    = REF_TRANS_CODE.BILL_SYSTEM_ID
AND FACT_TAX.TRANSCODE_ID           = REF_TRANS_CODE.TRANS_CODE_ID
AND DIM_HIERARCHY.BILL_SYSTEM_ID    = REF_CHARGE_GROUP.BILL_SYSTEM_ID
AND FACT_TAX.CHARGE_GROUP_ID        = REF_CHARGE_GROUP.CHARGE_GROUP_ID
AND FACT_TAX.BILL_SYSTEM_ID         = REF_STCNTRY.BILL_SYSTEM_ID
AND FACT_TAX.STCNTRY_ID             = REF_STCNTRY.STCNTRY_ID
AND FACT_TAX.TAX_ID                 = REF_TAX.TAX_ID
AND FACT_TAX.BILL_SYSTEM_ID         = REF_TAX.BILL_SYSTEM_ID
AND DIM_HIERARCHY.ACCT_ID           = DIM_LOCATION.ACCT_ID (+)
AND DIM_HIERARCHY.BILL_SYSTEM_ID    = DIM_LOCATION.BILL_SYSTEM_ID (+)
AND DIM_HIERARCHY.SERVICE_ID        = DIM_LOCATION.SERVICE_ID (+)
AND DIM_HIERARCHY.ACCT_PART_KEY     = DIM_LOCATION.ACCT_PART_KEY (+)
AND DIM_HIERARCHY.BILL_SYSTEM_ID    = REF_BPI_PROVIDER.BILL_SYSTEM_ID (+)
AND DIM_HIERARCHY.PROVIDER_ID       = REF_BPI_PROVIDER.SVC_PRVDR_ID (+)
AND DIM_HIERARCHY.ACCT_ID           = DIM_SUB_ADDL_INFO.ACCT_ID (+)
AND DIM_HIERARCHY.GROUP_ID          = DIM_SUB_ADDL_INFO.GROUP_ID (+)
AND DIM_HIERARCHY.SUB_ACCT_ID       = DIM_SUB_ADDL_INFO.SUB_ACCT_ID (+)
AND DIM_HIERARCHY.BILL_SYSTEM_ID    = DIM_SUB_ADDL_INFO.BILL_SYSTEM_ID (+)
ORDER BY TEMP_DCS.ACCT_ID, TEMP_DCS.INVOICE_NUM, TEMP_DCS.INV_DATE, DIM_HIERARCHY.GROUP_ID, DIM_HIERARCHY.SUB_ACCT_ID, DIM_HIERARCHY.SERVICE_ID) a) WHERE rnum  > 0
and rnum <= 10000
```

Comment: Not really relevant to your issue, but you might want to consider switching to modern ANSI join syntax instead of Oracle's old syntax, particularly for outer joins.

Answer (score 1):

Your inner query has multiple columns with the same names, albeit from different tables; those seem to be:

```
ACCT_ID (from DIM_HIERARCHY and TEMP_DCS)
CHARGE_GROUP_ID
INV_DATE
INVOICE_NUM
PRODUCT_TYPE_ID
```

The outer query can't cope with that ambiguity. You need to alias the clashing columns so the names are unique in the outer query.

---

As a simple demo of the issue:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT a.* ,
    ROWNUM rnum
  FROM
(
  -- replacing your entire inner query with somethign simple
  select dummy, dummy from dual
) a) WHERE rnum  > 0
and rnum <= 10000;

SQL Error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
```

If you alias the columns the issue goes away:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT a.* ,
    ROWNUM rnum
  FROM
(
  -- replacing your entire inner query with somethign simple
  select dummy as dummy1, dummy as dumym2 from dual
) a) WHERE rnum  > 0
and rnum <= 10000;

D D       RNUM
- - ----------
X X          1
```

Answer (score 0):

You want your pagination query (if using rownum) to be in the form of:

```
select * 
  from ( select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(n) */ 
  a.*, ROWNUM rnum 
      from ( your_query_goes_here, 
      with order by ) a 
      where ROWNUM <= 
      :MAX_ROW_TO_FETCH ) 
where rnum  >= :MIN_ROW_TO_FETCH;
```

You seem to stick both the upper and lower limits in the same place (among other things).  You have:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT a.* ,
    ROWNUM rnum
  FROM
(
select ...
ORDER BY TEMP_DCS.ACCT_ID, TEMP_DCS.INVOICE_NUM, TEMP_DCS.INV_DATE, DIM_HIERARCHY.GROUP_ID, DIM_HIERARCHY.SUB_ACCT_ID, DIM_HIERARCHY.SERVICE_ID) a) 
WHERE rnum  > 0 and rnum <= 10000
```

You probably want:

```
select * 
  from ( select a.*, ROWNUM rnum 
      from ( select ... from ... ORDER BY ...) a 
      where ROWNUM <= 10000 ) 
where rnum  >= 0;
```